# When is it optional to use ‘$’ character before a variable name in bash?

Tags: bash

Could someone please explain why this works, specifically the fact that I am not using ‘$’ character before the names of the variables inside the if statement? I have searched the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), but could not find an explanation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

one="$1"
two="$2"
three="$3"
four="$4"

if [[ one -le two ]] && [[ three -ge four ]]; then
        echo "TRUE:  $one <= $two && $three >= $four"
else
        echo "FALSE: $one <= $two && $three >= $four"
fi
```

I have also tested it with a loop like this, which works perfectly

```
for x1 in {1..3}; do
for x2 in {1..3}; do
for x3 in {1..3}; do
for x4 in {1..3}; do ./test $x1 $x2 $x3 $x4;
done; done; done; done | sort
```

Comment: `$x1 $x2 $x3 $x4` has dollar signs, does it not?

Comment: It works because `-le` and `-ge` interpret their arguments in a numeric context; when you pass something that looks like a variable name in a numeric context, bash tries looking at whether the variable's _contents_ are a number.

Comment: BTW, I don't know what your `./test $x1 $x2 $x3 $x4` example is supposed to prove.

Comment: Also, `sh` and `bash` are two different shells. A question should be tagged for one or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: As an aside, there is virtually no reason to use the arithmetic comparison operators  inside `[[ ... ]]`. If you can use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`, you can also use `(( ... ))` instead. `if (( one <= two && three >= four )); then`.

Comment: And as a defensive measure, I would prefer to use the dollar sign. If you forget to define `one`, for example, then `(( one -le two ))` will silently behave the same as `(( 0 -le two ))`, while `(( $one < $two ))` will behave like `(( < $two ))` and produce a syntax error immediately.

Comment: @chepner could you please elaborate a bit regarding the use of (( ... )) instead of [[ ... ]], specifically why would I choose to use one over the other. Thanks. (I got it... Arithmetic Expansion). Thx anyway!

Comment: `((...))` is specifically designed for arithmetic expressions; it uses "real" comparison operators like `<=` instead of cryptic legacy operators like `-le`, and is virtually guaranteed to be available if `[[ ... ]]` is available. (By which I mean, both `[[ ... ]]` and `(( ...))` are non-standard, but `bash` provides both, and I'm not aware of any shell that provides `[[...]]` but *not* `((...)))`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the description of [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) the description of the arithmetic comparison operators (`-lt`, `-gt`, etc.) says:

> When used with the [[ command, *Arg1* and *Arg2* are evaluated as arithmetic expressions (see [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic)).

And when you follow that link it says:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

And the description of [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) -- `$((expression))` says:

> All tokens in the expression undergo parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and quote removal. ... The evaluation is performed according to the rules listed below (see Shell Arithmetic).

Comment: Perfect answer, exactly what I was looking for, unlike the shoot from the hip approach and the unnecessary rhetoric that we see so much of these days. Thanks very much!

Comment: @corisco, if your intended question was "Why does this work?", you might have asked that; what you actually asked was "When does this work?". The "when" question reads as asking for a list of the contexts where the given thing works, whereas the answer you accepted explains _why_ it works, but not what/where the relevant contexts are, and thus doesn't comprehensively explain _when_ one is or isn't in such a context. Point being that "exactly what [you were] looking for" appears to differ from what you actually requested.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question begins "Could someone please explain why this works" and then goes on to say that he couldn't find it in the documentation. I found it in the documentation for him.

Comment: @Barmar, ahh. I tend to read the title as the core question itself (as it's what people other than the OP who find the question in a search engine / the front page / etc will be using to make their decision on whether to click through and read), and the body as mere focus and clarification; but if one ignores the title, that makes a great deal of sense.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tend to treat the title as a brief summary, and don't expect it to express all the nuances.

Answer (score 7):

Dollar signs are optional *inside an arithmetic context*. This is any context where a value is going to be interpreted as a number.

- `$(( ... ))` creates an arithmetic context in all POSIX shells
- `(( ... ))` creates an arithmetic context in bash, including in `for ((expr1; expr2; expr3))`.
- `let` creates an arithmetic context in shells (like bash) that support that ancient, pre-POSIX, nonstandard syntax.
- In `${array[idx]}` or `array[idx]=value`, `idx` is evaluated as arithmetic as long as the array has not been declared to be associative.
- In `[[ value1 -le value2 ]]`, because `-le` is an arithmetic operator (it only does numeric comparisons, not string comparisons), both `value1` and `value2` are parsed as arithmetic. This is also true for `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-gt` and `-ge`.
- In `${string:start:len}`, both `start` and `len` are arithmetic contexts.
- When `declare -i variable` has declared a variable to have a numeric type, and `variable=value` is subsequently run, `value` is an arithmetic context.

Note that this is **not** true for arithmetic comparisons inside `test` or `[` commands; `test` (whether or not called under the name `[`) acts like a regular shell command rather than special syntax (despite having a built-in implementation as a performance optimization).

Comment: I am surprised by the substring case `${parameter:offset:length}` and the `declare -i` case. The manual does say so: *length and offset are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).*, but I never registered that.